# How can I click on one element and listen for a change in another element's value?

Tags: javascript

upon clicking element with attribute 'data-one' above,  an update to an email field's value occurs. how can I detect if there was a change - the new update?  note that there is an async process that updates the email address post-clicking

```
$('a[data-one]').on('click',  function() {
  $('input#field_email_address').on('change',  function() {
    console.log('email value was change  detected');
  });
});
```

Comment: how the update is happening ?

Comment: What's wrong with the code included? You can use `.one()` instead I suppose (or remove the listener), but it seems to do what you want.

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense. Everytime a user clicks on the `a`, a new change detector is registered. Are you sure this is correct.?

Comment: You might want to describe the purpose and not the outcome. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: FYI: adding an event handler via click means every click bind an event so if someone double clicks, you just added two event listeners.

Comment: @PranavCBalan there is an async process that updates the email address post-clicking

Comment: ok, so maybe this would help you if you want to observe the change being applied on DOM element [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), you can create a new instance of MutationObserver and attached to the input and based on the change you can trigger your event.

Comment: Thank you @Ma'mounothman I also tried a setTimeout and added the detection as a separate function/method.

Answer (score 2):

Move the `change` event code out of the `click` event code and in the `click` event code just update the `email` field as needed.

But, you'll need to manually trigger the `change` event of that field because `change` only fires when the field loses focus, which it won't if done with code.

```js
$('a[data-one]').on('click',  function() {
   $('input#field_email_address').val("CHANGED!");
   $('input#field_email_address').trigger("change");
});

$('input#field_email_address').on('change',  function() {
  console.log('email value was changed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-one="something">Test</a>
<input id="field_email_address">
```

Comment: May be a misunderstanding on my part, but this would log `"email value was changed"` on every click regardless of whether or not anything changed, as opposed to "Detecting if there was a change" as OP mentions.

Comment: @TylerRoper from the code he posted, this answer seems to be the thing he is looking for.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman Not to be facetious, but if the code was working as intended then OP wouldn't be asking for us for help fixing it XD. But you may be correct, I suppose we'll need some clarification.

Comment: Without eliciting better input, it's difficult to know why the expressed behavior is useful. Solving the problem of attachment doesn't really tell us why the OP thought they needed it in the first place (binding observer, validation, something else?).

Comment: @TylerRoper, agree with you on this.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman the email update occurs separately via sign-on and the sign-on process updates the email. the email is initially empty

Answer (score 2):

Right now you are adding a `change` event listener every time that you click on the `a[data-one]` button.

You can check the value of the email field by using the `.val()` method. Compare the current value against a previously stored value and see if it differs. If it does, store the new value and log your message.

```
var emailValue = '';
$('a[data-one]').on('click',  function() {
  var newEmailValue = $('input#field_email_address').val();
  if (emailValue !== newEmailValue) {
    console.log('email value was changed');
    emailValue = newEmailValue;
  }
});
```

Comment: may want to set the initial emailValue to an empty string so it doesn't detect a change without the user entering anything.